# Minimal decoherence for a 3 levels system

Tags: decoherence, bloch-sphere

In the case of a two level system driven by a monochromatic excitation, a minimal amount of decoherence results from the finite lifetime of the excited state. In the optical bloch equations, the excited state population is exponentially damped with a rate $\Gamma$ and the off-diagonal terms $\rho_{eg}$ are exponentially damped by a factor $\gamma\ge\Gamma/2$.

How does this generalizes to a 3-levels system ${a,b,c}$ ? How is $\gamma_{ac}$ related to $\Gamma_a$, $\Gamma_b$ and $\Gamma_c$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget in the 2 level system you also get increase in population due to decay to the ground state:

$\rho_{ground} \propto -\gamma_{excited}*\rho_{excited}$

For a 3-level system the minimal decoherence is damped by 1/2 of its individual coherence components. So for example:

$\gamma_{ab} \propto \frac{1}{2}(\Gamma_a + \Gamma_b)$